Radio Drama 'free range' clones of rich people are grown so replacement organs will be available for them
I heard these about 2010 on BBC Radio 4. It seemed to have been written recently.
The protagonist is a lady going for a job interview at the place, several buildings on one site, where the clones are raised.
The clones walk around wearing overalls. They are taught a very limited vocabulary and to follow simple instructions. The people running the place still claim they are not intelligent.
It is really haunting. One of the clones Carter 5 has his eyes removed when the rich young man he is cloned from damages his. The clone in kept sedated thereafter in 'high dependency '. Another clone sees him, goes back to the barracks and say to his peers "Carter 5 no eyes."
At one point one of the clones is asking too many questions and they decide to kill him. His identical clone brother swaps identification bracelets with him, sacrificing himself to save his brothers life.
There were several 30 minute installments.

Wow, I knew of two films that covered the same ground (The Island and Parts: The Clonus Horror) but an audio play on the same topic is new information.
I wonder if it's worth a question if there are any more?

The BBC audio play is awesome!

@VBartilucci and don't forget "Never Let Me Go".

This sounds like Jefferson 37, a BBC Radio 4 drama in 4 episodes by Jenny Stephens. The drama indeed deals with clones being produced in order to provide organ parts. This website provides the description:

What happens when spare-part surgery becomes the norm? Will clones be
created purely with the intention of providing body parts and organs
for those who can afford it? If so, what will life be like for those
clones?
Written by Jenny Stephens – four episodes of approx 30 minutes each in
high quality MP3.
Episode 1: Marketing expert Eleanor visits
Abbotsville, where clones are created purely for organ replacement.
But are they really inhuman?
Episode 2: Eleanor Riley discovers more
about the true nature of the work of Abbotsville, the clone farm.
Episode 3: Dr Abbots tries to prove that clones have no emotions.
Meanwhile, Jefferson and Lucy discover what really happened to Carter
5.
Episode 4: In the thriller’s conclusion, Dr Abbots finds his “party trick” used against him, and Paul Smith takes advantage of the chaos.

In particular, the series deals with the fate of one of the clones, "Carter 5", whose eyes are removed.
The episodes are not currently available from the BBC, but can be accessed from the Internet Archive.

This sounds like a dramatisation of Kazuo Ishiguro's 'Never let me go'

Kathy H describes herself as a carer for donors. She reminisces about
her time spent at Hailsham, a boarding school, where the teachers are
known as guardians. The children are closely monitored and are
instructed on the importance of producing art and staying healthy;
smoking is taboo. The students' best art is selected by Madame for a
gallery. Kathy develops a close friendship with two other students:
Ruth C and Tommy D. Kathy develops a fondness for Tommy, looking after
him when he is bullied and having private talks with him. However,
Tommy and Ruth form a relationship instead. In an isolated incident,
the guardian Miss Lucy tells the students that they are being raised
to donate organs to others (like saviour siblings), and it is
predetermined that they will die young. Miss Lucy is removed from the
school as a result; the students passively accept their fate.

Quote from wikipedia

Not the show I was describing but great book, one of my favourites.

@JudithJones I realised it wasn't the one when I saw the correct answer, still a very good book with the same idea.

@JudithJones if you like this kind of bittersweet/melancholy writing, Kazuo Ishiguro as more scifi like it: I recommend "Klara and the Sun"... Being the same author, the writing style is entirely the same, and the themes are similar (the plot and setting are different, of course).

Thanks AndresF I have read that one
